# Save lines to separate files

Tags: awk, gawk

I have a file -->
http://wklej.org/id/1403118/

Creating separate files

```
awk '/O[0-9]{5}/{print > $0}' file
```

In each file I want to put the model and subsequent lines.

An example of the first two files

file Name --> **O00001(odjazdxyz)**

```
O00001(odjazdxyz)
G91 G28 Y0 Z0 
G90 
M99
```

file Name --> **O00001(049-479514)**

```
O00001(049-479514)
/ M97 P1 (FR25) 
M97 P2 (FR8) 
M30 
N1 T2 G43 H02 G54 M06 
G00 X1. Y-12.5 Z1. M08 
S890 M03 
G01 X-58. F250. 
Y12.5 
X1. 
G00 Y-12.5 Z0 
G01 X-58. 
Y12.5 
X2. M09 
G00 Y170. Z300. N1 M99 

N2 T8 G43 H08 G54 M06 (FR8) 
G00 X0 Y57. Z2. M08 
S2785 M03 
G01 Z-4. F250. M09 
G00 Z2. Y380. N2 M99
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
awk '/O[0-9]/{out=$0} out{print > out}' file
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. They work, but after removal of the first line of the file. 
Without removing the first line is the error: `awk command line: 1: (FILENAME = b FNR = 1) fatal error: expression for `> `'redirection has null string value`